# Seeking a proof equivalent to the story "She said that I would stop her if she told me why she is leaving, so I decided to stop her anyway!"

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I am looking for an interesting mathematical proof which is equivalent to the story:

> "She said that I would stop her if she told me why she is leaving, so I decided to stop her anyway!"

Mathematically, I guess, this could be phrased, for a language $\mathcal L$ in propositional logic, as:
$$\Big(\exists A\in Prop(\mathcal L) \,\,\text{s.t.}\,\,\vdash A\,\,\&\,\, A\implies B\Big)\implies B. $$

I am no logician and probably am wrong regarding to the last part, so please correct me, as long as my informal description is clear.

Edit: Clearly, there are many situations where you know
\begin{align*}
\vdash& A\\
\vdash& A\implies B\vee C\\
\vdash& (B\implies D)\&(C\implies D)\\
&\quad\Downarrow\\
\vdash& D\end{align*}

For example, have a function with two fixed points, each of which is rational, and have a convergent recursive sequence defined by this function. You know it converges to a fixed point but you do not know to which, however you do know that the limit is rational.

$\textbf{Edit:}$

In my example, it looks like $A$ could be "She was leaving to save her brother from Dracula" and $B$ is "I stopped her from leaving".

Comment: Could you provide a definition of your terms A and B? If I am not mistaken, (A&A->B)->B currently has: "she told me why she was leaving" as A, and "stop her leaving" as B.
If this is the case, then you have presumed that she told you why she was leaving, which the original sentence does not state is the case.

Comment: @user400188 I edited the question, check it out.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The original phrase**

> She said that I would stop her if she told me why she is leaving, so I decided to stop her anyway!"  $~(0)$

The phrase $(0)$ reads as $(1)$, which is logically equivalent to the statement $B$. In $(1)$, I have symbolized "I stopped her" as $B$, and "she told me why she is leaving" as $W$.

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
(W\rightarrow B)~\&~B
\end{equation}

Careful reading of $(0)$ shows that the girl did not explain why she was leaving, so it's not necessary for the other person to stop her.

**Your statement**

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\Big(\exists A\in Prop(\mathcal L) \,\,\text{s.t.}\,\,\vdash A\,\,\&\,\, A\implies B\Big)\implies B
\end{equation}

There are a few nuances with (2). To best state explicitly that the right hand side of $(2)$ is a sentence in propositional logic, you should bind both $A$ and $B$, as opposed to just $A$.

Secondly, you have placed the quantification and meta level proof symbol ($\vdash$), in the antecedent of your implication using brackets. This means that $(2)$ is equivilent to $(3)$, which is clearly not what you intended to say.

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\big(\exists A\in Prop(\mathcal L) \,\,\text{s.t.}\,\,\nvdash A\,\,\&\,\, A\implies B\Big)\lor B
\end{equation}

A better symbolization of $(3)$ is $(4)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\exists A,B \in Prop(\mathcal L) \,\,\text{s.t.}\,\,\vdash (A\,\,\&\,\, A\implies B)\implies B
\end{equation}

**Your first edit**

Your edit is a lot clearer, and the symbolization for this statement is good. It has a different logical form to $(0)$ however, and appears to be unrelated.

Comment: If you are looking for a guide to learn logic from, you can't do much better than the Stanford online course. http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/index.php